# Visual Studio Inadmissible element "else" in expression

Tags: c#

```
  private void buttan_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = textBox1.Text;

        if (a == "Well")
        {
            pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        }
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"c:\Users\Galym\Desktop\123.mp4";
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
        }

        else
        {  MessageBox.Show("Try again");
        }
```

Inadmissible element "else" in expression 
Help me to find error

Comment: `else` needs to come right after an `if` body.

Comment: you have a code block after `if {}`, the two `}{` after `pictureBox.Visible = false;` appears useless.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your if statement syntax is a bit off.

```
private void buttan_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = textBox1.Text;

        if (a == "Well")
        {
            pictureBox1.Visible = false;

            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"c:\Users\Galym\Desktop\123.mp4";
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
        }

        else
        {  
            MessageBox.Show("Try again");
        }
```

Assuming you want to run all three lines of code when the if statement is hit, then this should work for you.

The way you do it, the compiler doesn't think there is an else block for that if statement, therefore it will throw an error at the else, since it isn't being paired up.

The else statement has to come directly after any if or else ifs you have.

Answer (score 1):

Your `else` is being evaluated as an `else` expression of the second code block (the block of expressions surrounding the brackets), in this case:

```
{
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"c:\Users\Galym\Desktop\123.mp4";
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
}
```

Since that block doesn't contain an `if` (the `if` in your code is before that block), the `else` is invalid, and that's what the compiler is telling.

In case you want those two lines to evaluate when the `if` expression is true, then do:

```
if (a == "Well")
{
    pictureBox1.Visible = false;
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"c:\Users\Galym\Desktop\123.mp4";
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
}
else
{  
    MessageBox.Show("Try again");
}
```

Otherwise, if you absolutely want to have a code block (for some reason, although there's absolutely none in that code), you should put that block inside the other block, like:

```
if (a == "Well")
{
    pictureBox1.Visible = false;

    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"c:\Users\Galym\Desktop\123.mp4";
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
    }
}
else
{  
    MessageBox.Show("Try again");
}
```

This doesn't do absolutely anything (since you don't have any variables in it there's no scope issues), but it's legal.